# Is vinyl flashing as easy to work with as metal flashing?

Tags: flashing

I have seen a lot of vinyl flashing at the big box stores recently.  [Duraflash](http://www.duraflash.net/) is a name brand  that I have seen most.  It seems they just come in long rolls just like unbent flashing does, and you can bend them to the shape you want (and they'll hold it?)  For people that have used it, is it just better/easier to use metal flashing (except for Aluminum since it corrodes against PT wood), or is vinyl flashing the next best thing?

Comment: Another option is "liquid-applied flashing" which I've heard is becoming more popular.

Comment: I used it FLAT under the bottom of the siding and I liked it (although it's easy to puncture e.g when the person cutting housewrap is not aware that the flashing is not metal). I am also planning to use it to cover fascia board but I don't see how I could bend it, it's not going to hold the shape. I would have to staple it a lot which defeats the purpose. Instead, I am going to put metal L-profile 1.5"x1.5"  to cover the BOTTOM EDGE of the board, and then cover the front 1.5" with the 8" vinyl flashing (and tuck it under the actual drip edge above fascia)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier to cut and you're less likely to cut your fingers on it.  I've never used rolls but the pre-cut sections and they were easy to put in.  Just follow the directions.

Comment: what directions? Are there ways to bend it to 90 degrees? I am afraid that scoring it with any kind of knife would be too risky, and without it it would not hold the shape at all.